# How to work in ANdroid Studio in a Group/Team?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Some friends of mine and I are developing an App as a school project in Android Studio because the only language we currently speak is Java, and we don't know how to work as Team e.g. How do we share the code with all of us, or if we shall do it with GitHub how does that work too? We have little experience in these things and would appreciate it a lot if you could help me what we could do and what is the best way to proceed

Comment: You're headed in the right direction. Maybe this can help - https://youtube.com/watch?v=eulnSXkhE7I

Answer (score 1):

You need a distributed version control system.

The most common version control system is git, but svn and mercurial also exist.

Then the version control system needs a centralized way to distribute the latest changes to everybody. The most common is Github; there is also Bitbucket and Gitlab.

Since you ask very general questions, I think the easier way would be using Github because it is the most common, and it integrates fairly easily with Android Studio. Even when solving differences between files (conflicts), Android Studio offers some handy dandy dialogs to ease the editions.